# Agragar textCtrl dinámicamente (en tiempo de ejecución) a un sizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxwidgets, wxpython

Estoy creando una ventana sencilla donde el usuario va a ingresar un numero `n` de valores, es decir, el usuario decide cuantos valores va a ingresar. Quiero que los ingrese en un `wx.TextCtrl` y agregar en tiempo real en el evento del botón `ok`. (la función del evento del botón se llama `iniciarCacillas()` ) los `wx.textCtrl` a un `sizer` donde organizo todo.

El problema es que al momento de hacerlo y crear los `TextCtrl` de esta forma para luego agregarlos al `sizer` no funciona, se quedan los `TextCtrl` en la  esquina del `frame`, uno sobre otro.

Este es mi código:

```
import wx


class ventana(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        app = wx.App()
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title = "Ajute De Curvas", size = (500, 700))
        #paneles

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        #sizer

        self.sUno = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sDos = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sBox = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, self, "Introduzca el valor de los puntos")
        self.sTres = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sCuatro = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sCinco = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        #butons

        self.bCalcular = wx.Button(self, -1, "Calcular")
        self.bBorrar = wx.Button(self, -1, "Borrar")
        self.bOk = wx.Button(self, -1, "Ok", size = (30,28))

        #labels
        self.lUno = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "numero de Puntos (n) : ")
        self.lDos = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Introduzca El Valor De Los Puntos")
        self.lTres = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Valores De X ")
        self.lCuatro = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Valores De Y ")
        self.lCinco = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Lineal")
        self.lSeis = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " ".ljust(20 , " ") + "r = ")
        self.lSiete = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Cuadratico")
        self.lOcho = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " ".ljust(20 , " ") + "r = ")
        self.lNueve = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Grado 3")
        self.lDiez = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " ".ljust(20 , " ") + "r = ")
        self.lOnce = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Grado 4")
        self.lDoce = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " ".ljust(20 , " ") + "r = ")
        self.lTrece = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Grado 5")
        self.lCatorce = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " ".ljust(20 , " ") + "r = ")

        #textControl
        self.tUno = wx.TextCtrl(self, size = (50, 25))
        self.listaT = [[],[]]

        # Static line
        self.lineOne = wx.StaticLine(self, -1, size = (430, 1), style = (wx.LI_HORIZONTAL))
        self.lineTwo = wx.StaticLine(self, -1, size =(430, 1), style = (wx.LI_HORIZONTAL) )

        #organizando sizers
        self.sDos.Add(self.lUno, wx.SizerFlags().Centre().Border(wx.ALL, 10))
        self.sDos.Add(self.tUno,  wx.SizerFlags().Centre().Border(wx.ALL, 13))
        self.sDos.Add(self.bOk,  wx.SizerFlags().Centre().Border(wx.ALL, 13))
        self.sUno.Add(self.sDos, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.sUno.Add(self.lDos,wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 13) )
        self.sUno.Add(self.lineOne,wx.SizerFlags().Centre().Border(wx.ALL, 13))

        self.sTres.Add(self.lTres,wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 13) )
        self.sBox.Add(self.sTres, 1 , wx.Left)

        self.sCuatro.Add(self.lCuatro, wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 13))
        self.sBox.Add(self.sCuatro, 1 , wx.Left)

        self.sUno.Add(self.sBox, 2, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 13)
        self.sUno.Add(self.lineTwo, wx.SizerFlags().Centre().Border(wx.ALL, 13))

        self.sCinco.Add(self.bCalcular, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        self.sCinco.Add(self.bBorrar, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL )
        self.sUno.Add(self.sCinco, 1 , wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)

        self.sUno.Add(self.lCinco, wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sUno.Add(self.lSeis, wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sUno.Add(self.lSiete, wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sUno.Add(self.lOcho, wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sUno.Add(self.lNueve , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sUno.Add(self.lDiez , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sUno.Add(self.lOnce , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sUno.Add(self.lDoce , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sUno.Add(self.lTrece , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sUno.Add(self.lCatorce , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))

        #eventos
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.iniciarCacillas, self.bOk)

        #acabados de la ventana
        self.SetSizer(self.sUno)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
        app.MainLoop()

    def iniciarCacillas(self, evt):
        #try:
        self.n = int(self.tUno.GetValue())

        for i in range(self.n):
            cUno = wx.TextCtrl(self)
            cDos = wx.TextCtrl(self)

            self.sTres.Add(cUno, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL , 10)
            self.sCuatro.Add(cDos, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL , 10)

            self.listaT[0].append(cUno)
            self.listaT[1].append(cDos)
        #except:
            #wx.MessageDialog(None, "Digite numeros validos", "SeeD.Inc Msj", wx.OK).ShowModal()


v = ventana()
```

Answer (score 0):

Si después de agregar los widgets, redimensionas la ventana verás como se recolocan correctamente.

El problema es que debes llamar explícitamente al método `Layout` de algún widget padre, el cual es llamado cuando se reciben eventos`EVT_SIZE`  (como redimensionar la ventana, de ahí el comportamiento anterior) si no hemos asignado nuestro propio handler. Esta llamada no se produce en este caso con simplemente añadir el widget al `Sizer`.

Puedes hacer `self.sBox.Layout` o `self.Layout`, dado que el evento se va a propagar, en el método mediante el que agregas los `TextCtrl`.

El código, con algunas modificaciones, podría quedar:

```
import wx


class Ventana(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title):        
        super().__init__(None, title=title, size=(500, 700))

        # paneles
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        # sizer
        self.sizer_uno = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer_dos = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer_box = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, self, "Introduzca el valor de los puntos")
        self.sizer_tres = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer_cuatro = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer_cinco = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # botones
        self.btn_calcular = wx.Button(self, -1, "Calcular")
        self.btn_borrar = wx.Button(self, -1, "Borrar")
        self.btn_ok = wx.Button(self, -1, "Ok", size=(30,28))

        # labels
        self.lbl_uno = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "numero de Puntos (n) : ")
        self.lbl_dos = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Introduzca El Valor De Los Puntos")
        self.lbl_tres = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Valores De X ")
        self.lbl_cuatro = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Valores De Y ")
        self.lbl_cinco = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Lineal")
        self.lbl_seis = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " ".ljust(20 , " ") + "r = ")
        self.lbl_siete = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Cuadratico")
        self.lbl_ocho = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " ".ljust(20 , " ") + "r = ")
        self.lbl_nueve = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Grado 3")
        self.lbl_diez = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " ".ljust(20 , " ") + "r = ")
        self.lbl_once = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Grado 4")
        self.lbl_doce = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " ".ljust(20 , " ") + "r = ")
        self.lbl_trece = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Grado 5")
        self.lbl_catorce = wx.StaticText(self, -1, " ".ljust(20 , " ") + "r = ")

        # textControl
        self.text_uno = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(50, 25))
        self.lista_text = [[], []]

        # Static line
        self.line_uno = wx.StaticLine(self, -1, size = (430, 1), style = (wx.LI_HORIZONTAL))
        self.line_dos = wx.StaticLine(self, -1, size =(430, 1), style = (wx.LI_HORIZONTAL) )

        # organizando sizers
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_uno, wx.SizerFlags().Centre().Border(wx.ALL, 10))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.text_uno,  wx.SizerFlags().Centre().Border(wx.ALL, 13))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.btn_ok,  wx.SizerFlags().Centre().Border(wx.ALL, 13))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.sizer_dos, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_dos,wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 13) )
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.line_uno,wx.SizerFlags().Centre().Border(wx.ALL, 13))

        self.sizer_tres.Add(self.lbl_tres,wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 13) )
        self.sizer_box.Add(self.sizer_tres, 1 , wx.Left)

        self.sizer_cuatro.Add(self.lbl_cuatro, wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 13))
        self.sizer_box.Add(self.sizer_cuatro, 1 , wx.Left)

        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.sizer_box, 2, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 13)
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.line_dos, wx.SizerFlags().Centre().Border(wx.ALL, 13))

        self.sizer_cinco.Add(self.btn_calcular, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        self.sizer_cinco.Add(self.btn_borrar, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL )
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.sizer_cinco, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)

        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_cinco, wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_seis, wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_siete, wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_ocho, wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_nueve , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_diez , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_once , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_doce , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_trece , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))
        self.sizer_uno.Add(self.lbl_catorce , wx.SizerFlags().Left().Border(wx.ALL, 9))

        # eventos
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.iniciar_casillas, self.btn_ok)

        # acabados de la ventana
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer_uno)
        self.Centre()


    def iniciar_casillas(self, evt):
        try:
            n = int(self.text_uno.GetValue())

        except ValueError:
            wx.MessageDialog(None, "Digite numeros validos",
                             "SeeD.Inc Msj", wx.OK).ShowModal()
        else:  
            for _ in range(n):
                text_ctrl_uno = wx.TextCtrl(self)
                text_ctrl_dos = wx.TextCtrl(self)

                self.sizer_tres.Add(text_ctrl_uno, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
                self.sizer_cuatro.Add(text_ctrl_dos, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)

                self.lista_text[0].append(text_ctrl_uno)
                self.lista_text[1].append(text_ctrl_dos)

            self.sizer_box.Layout()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    v = Ventana("Ajute De Curvas")
    v.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: OMG! muchas gracias, enserio, pensé muchas otras soluciones, pero solo andaba en quimeras, se mi maestro por favor :V